# Difficulties with Representation of Half Wave and Full Wave Rectifiers on PartSim

Tags: simulation, rectifier, graph

After tweaking the domains, the run-time duration of the simulation and the location of the probe I discovered that there was no mistake. Below I've attached a picture of the graph blown-up.

---

Recently I've become interested in self-studying electrical circuits and upon my scholastic quest I've stumbled upon a problem.

To my understanding, a half-wave rectifier is meant to eliminate the "negative portion" when graphed using a sine representation when tested on a simulator, but I don't seem to be getting the same result.

The other problem that I'm facing is trying to run a simulation of a full-wave rectifier.

I'm using PartSim, which is a completely free simulator (Not an expert with it... yet).

I'll attach some pictures of the circuits that I made and also the apparent simulation results.

Thanks in advance!

My Diagram of Half Wave Rect:
[image: Half Wave Rectifier]

Graph of Simulation of Half Wave Rectifier:
[image: Simulation of Half Wave Rectifier]

Zoomed in Depiction of Graph:
[image: Correct Graph]

My Diagram of Full Wave Rect:
[image: Full Wave Rectifier]

Comment: Are you sure you place the probe at the correct location? That is to say the net between the diode and the resistor?

Comment: Electrical and electronics it is not a "push button" matter or the "like" button on f/b. It is a science that includes personal skills, deep knowleges about the subject, many years spends on schools and involves, physics, mathematics, chemistry, philosophy, humor, sharp mind, friends.... just to count what is not on my side. I will watch here to learn together

Comment: @AndrejaKo, yes I believe so.

Comment: The "zoomed in depiction of graph" is not what you say it is. Have you read the very valid answer given by CAGT - your own answer explains nothing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you have a 1v offset

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see with your schematic is that you have two ground references. Your AC power supply is grounded, as well as D2 cathode. And the bridge rectifier DC output rail's ground is in fact the anode of D2 (even though not shown), the cathode of D3 being the positive (Vcc). Also note that your load R1 is connected between these two points. Now, am I missing a point or are both the anode and cathode of D2 grounded (D2 shorted)?